# Java Selenium - page object model - webdriver null pointer exception error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Feature file:

```
Feature: test of a webpage

@desktop
Scenario: Test landing page 
  Given Customer is on landing page
```

This is the step definition file:

```
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import pages.Landing Page;
import utils.BasePage;
import utils.ConfigureDriver;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static utils.BasePage.driver;

public class LandingPageStepDefs {
LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);
ScenarioContext scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
ConfigureDriver configureDriver = new ConfigureDriver();


@Given("Customer is on landing page")
public void customer_is_on_landing_page () {
    landingPage.clickConsent();
}

@Before("not @mobile")
public void beforeDesktop(Scenario scenario) {
    configureDriver.configureDesktop();
}
```

This is the LandingPage:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import utils.BasePage;
 
public class LandingPage extends BasePage {
 
    public LandingPage (WebDriver driver) {
       super(driver);
    }
 
    public void clickConsent() {
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"cookie-terms\"]/div/div/button/i")).click();
    } 
}
```

This is the BasePage:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions; 
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.Duration; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BasePage {
 
public static WebDriver driver;
 
    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
         this.driver = driver;
         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
 
     public static WebDriver getDriver() {
         return driver;
     } 
}
```

This is ConfigureDriver Page

```
package utils;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ConfigureDriver {
 
    public void configureDesktop() {
         ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
         WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
 
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
 
         driver.get("https://www.page.com/");
 
     } 
}
```

There is null pointer exception in step def here. Could you tell how to get rid of it ? Thanks in advance.
landingPage.clickConsent();

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit the `BasePage` class from `ConfigureDriver` class, also you have  to modify the WebDriver initialization line:

```
public class ConfigureDriver extends BasePage {

    public ConfigureDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void configureDesktop() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);    // modified this line

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.page.com/");

    }
}
```

Next time, post your question in brief and clear, also do the correct indentation.